# Typescript definition confusion

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition

This is how my typescript file looks like.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQuery {
    ColorThief:any;
}

class Color {
    isItDarkColor(rgb) {
        var rgbColors = rgb.toString().split(","),
            r = parseFloat(rgbColors[0]),
            g = parseFloat(rgbColors[1]),
            b = parseFloat(rgbColors[2]);
        var percentage = Math.sqrt(
                r * r * 0.299 +
                g * g * 0.587 +
                b * b * 0.114
            ) / 2.55;
        return (percentage < 70);
    }

    getColor(src) {
        var image = new Image,
            colorThief = new ColorThief();
        image.src = src;
        return colorThief.getColor(image);
    }
}
```

During compilation getting error message

`Cannot find name 'ColorThief'.`

Here is the color thief plugin that I want to use and it's already included in html markup

https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `new jQuery.ColorThief` if it's a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined it as a `jquery plugin` however its actually just a JavaScript class

Fix: Your definition should look like

```
interface ColorThief{
  new ():any;
}
```